# how to rename all the gdg base and all the versions at a time?

Tags: jcl

I have a GDG base with 1000+ version in it. I want to change  name all the files.
The existing file is DMXWCCA.R00.WI82XXX
I need a JCL program which has to rename the existing file as C02565.R00.WI82XXX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just allocate the Destination GDG and copy then using TSO.

Step1 - Define

```
//IDCAMS   EXEC PGM=IDCAMS,REGION=64M
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*  
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                
//SYSIN    DD * 
 DEFINE GDG                        - 
  (NAME('<Your new DSN>')              - 
   LIMIT(<Your limit>) NOEMPTY SCRATCH   )
```

Step2 - Rename

```
//RENAME   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01     
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*           
//SYSTSIN  DD *,SYMBOLS=JCLONLY  
 RENAME '<Your old DSN>.*' '<Your new DSN>.*'
```

I prefer to use symbols, therefore I left the entry at SYSTSIN.

Regards Andreas

Comment: this doesn't really answer his questions. OP has many GDGs they want to rename all at once, this solution only renames one at a time

Comment: @SaggingRufus Since * is entered as the last qualifier, it renames all the GDG  at once. I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you take a look at DFDSS. This is the kind of thing that DFDSS would do well.

Documentation here: https://www-304.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3SC236868/$file/adru000_v2r3.pdf

Find "Renaming data sets". Looks promising. No guarantees but worth a shot.